# Classification retraining after mathematica shutdown

Tags: machine-learning

I have the following problem with two sets of pictures which are loaded and trained. After the first trial it worked.

This is my code:

```
SBF = Classify[<| "bird" -> Import["E:\\Users\\Josh\\Pictures\\birds
\\*"], "fish" -> Import["E:\\Users\\Josh\\Pictures\\fish\\*"]|>, Method 
-> "NearestNeighbors"]

ClassifierFunction[]

SBF[{Import["E:\\User\\Josh\\Pictures\\unknown.jpg"]}]
```

Then I saved and restarted Mathematica retrained the model and get this message:

> Input expression ClassifierFunction[] contains insufficient \
>   information to interpret the result. >>

Comment: I don't understand what that `ClassifierFunction[]` means in your code. Is that supposed to represent Mathematica output? Also, are you sure that the images used in training loaded correctly the second time around?

Comment: It works now. For some reason I used the wrong cell which always used the precalculated value.

Comment: OK, glad to hear it's working. Thank you for letting us know!